# JAVA | CXF JAXRS Non-Spring client

Tags: java, client, cxf, jax-rs, kerberos

We are trying to come up with a non-spring client for our cxf jaxrs services.
(Not a web-client)

We have the following element in our spring-context (for enabling kerberos authentication):

```
<http:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
        <http:authorization>
            <sec:AuthorizationType>Negotiate</sec:AuthorizationType>
        </http:authorization>
</http:conduit>
```

Any idea how this can be converted to java code ?

Sample client code:

```
JAXRSClientFactoryBean clientBean = new JAXRSClientFactoryBean();
clientBean.setResourceClass(ServiceClassName.class);
clientBean.setAddress(restful-service-url);
```

CXF documentation doesn't specify this clearly :
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-CreatingclientsprogrammaticallywithnoSpringdependencies

Thanks,
Gayathri

Comment: Have you checked [How to configure the HTTPConduit for the SOAP Client](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport%28includingSSLsupport%29-HowtoconfiguretheHTTPConduitfortheSOAPClient?)? It shows how to create `HTTPConduit` and what you need is to create `AuthorizationPolicy` and set it;s type to `Negotiate`.

Comment: Yes. But in our case its a restful client and 'clientBean' in the above code doesnt expose 'getConduit' method. On a related note, it exposes 'getConduitSelector' and 'setConduitSelector' , but its not clear if thats where AuthorizationPolicy needs to be set.

Answer (score 0):

dma_k was pointing you to the correct information for SOAP services. If you are looking to the direct answer for REST services, check http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-ConfiguringClientsatRuntime

```
YourService proxy = JAXRSClientFactory.create(YourService.class);
ClientConfiguration config = WebClient.getConfig(proxy);
HTTPConduit conduit1 = (HTTPConduit)config.getConduit();
System.out.println(conduit1.getClient().getProxyServer());
```

This code allows you to access the conduit of your REST service, and then configure it as you want. You just have to pass through the WebClient.getConfig() method.

Regards,
Gabriel